# StarWars API: Create buttons to move between planet pages

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api

I'm using the very famous StarWars API and I should extrapolate the data from the first page of the planets (and so far I have no problems). Sure, I had to do some research to figure out how to do it, but I finally succeeded. But now there is another problem.

I would have to create buttons that allow the user to go to the second page of the planets and get data from that page. And here I am stuck, because I don't know how to do it, because then, using the Next Button, the user must be able to go to the third,, fourth, fifth and sixth page, and then returning back to the first page of planets.

So I looked at the URL and thought we could bind a variable to it that is itself bound to a value provided by the buttons. In this way, if the user clicks on the button the chosen value should be given to the variable located after the URL. To do this I used the `++ value` and `--value` patterns, which do what they should: increase and decrease the value.

However, this is not transmitted to the URL and the new fetch process does not take place to get the info from the pages.
But I did something wrong and I don't know what.

Could you please help me? ..

This is the problematic code:

```
  value = 1

  const prevButton = document.createElement("button");
  prevButton.innerText = 'Prev Page'
  prevButton.setAttribute("id", "prev-button")
  document.body.append(prevButton);
  prevButton.style.cssText = "background-color: violet; width: 150px; height: 45px; 
 transform: translateY(-725%); margin-left: -10px;"
  prevButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  return --value
  })
 
  const nextButton = document.createElement("button");
  nextButton.innerText = 'Next Page'
  nextButton.setAttribute("id", "next-button")
  document.body.append(nextButton);
  nextButton.style.cssText = "background-color: violet; width: 150px; height: 45px; transform: translateY(-825%); margin-left: 90.5%;"
  nextButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
   return ++value
  })


    const response = await fetch ('https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=' + value);
    const planetsData = await response.json().then(planetsData => {
    let results = planetsData.results;
    results.forEach(planet => {
    const wrapper = document.createElement("wrapper")
    square.append(wrapper);
    wrapper.style.cssText = 'background-color: red; width: 200px; height: 250px; margin: auto; margin-top: 1.5%; margin-left: 50px; display: flex; flex-wrap: nowrap"; flex-direction: row;'
    wrapper.innerHTML = '<div><h1>Name: ' + planet.name + '</h1>' + 
    '<h3><p>Climate: ' + planet.climate + '</p></h3>' + 
    '<p>Population: ' + planet.population + 
    '<p>Terrain: ' + planet.terrain  + '</p></div>';
   });
   })
```

Comment: You're only calling your fetch once the entire time. You should maybe put that in its own function and then call it from your button handlers with the updated value.

Comment: I tried to do that man, but it didn't work

Comment: make an function to fetch data , then on your event listener , bind your fetch function (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener?retiredLocale=de#getting_data_into_and_out_of_an_event_listener )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example that embellishes on my comment. I've hardcoded the buttons here for convenience but the key points are:

1. getting that fetch process in its own function so that it can be called whenever a button is clicked
2. Using the `next` and `previous` properties of the returned data to guide which page should be displayed next.

```js
// Cache the elements
const planets = document.querySelector('.planets');
const buttons = document.querySelector('.buttons');
const previous = document.querySelector('[data-id="previous"]');
const next = document.querySelector('[data-id="next"]');

// Add one listener to the button container
buttons.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// Initialise the base endpoint, and `data`
const base = 'https://swapi.dev/api/planets/?page=1';
let data = {};

// Fetch the first page
fetchData();

// When a button is clicked grab its
// data id (which will be either "previous" or "next"
// and use that to fetch the next page
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.button')) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    fetchData(id);
  }
}

// Pass in the value of the data attribute as `id`
// If the data has a previous/next property
// use its value to get the previous/next page, otherwise
// use the base endpoint
// Then create some HTML from the data and add it to
// the page, finally updating the disabled state of
// each button
async function fetchData(id) {
  const endpoint = data[id] || base;
  const res = await fetch(endpoint);
  data = await res.json();
  const html = createHTML(data.results);
  planets.innerHTML = html;
  previous.disabled = !data.previous ? true : false;
  next.disabled = !data.next ? true : false;
}

// Pass in the new data, `map` over it, and return
// a string of HTML
function createHTML(data) {
  return data
    .map(planet => {
      return `
        <section class="planet">
          <h4>${planet.name}</h4>
          <p>Population: ${planet.population}</p>
          <p>Terrain: ${planet.terrain}</p>
        </section>
      `;
    })
    .join('');
}
```

```css
.planet { border: 1px solid #efefef; padding: 0.4em; }
.button:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<section class="buttons">
  <button data-id="previous" class="button">Prev</button>
  <button data-id="next" class="button">Next</button>
</section>
<section class="planets"></section>
```

Additional documentation

- [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)
- [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [`matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)
- [Data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Thank you Andy, but it doesn't work. In console i have an error report: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"

Comment: Have you used this example in its entirety including the HTML, or are you using your code too? It might just be the script running before the DOM is ready and there are ways to solve that. Moving the `<script>` element (and code) to just before the `</body>` tag might do it...